# Automate scroll function of individual grid

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I wanted to select values from web table which is in infinite scroll 
  I have tried JavaScript executors but it doesn't work for me

Comment: <div id="grid_StudyGrid_records" class="w2ui-grid-records" onscroll="w2ui['StudyGrid'].scroll(event);" style="top: 26px; overflow: hidden auto; left: 27px;">

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [mcve] and edit your post accordingly. Don't add images to the post